# How to access GParamSpec-related functions from Python GObject Instrospection?

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygobject, gobject

I am wondering whether GObject Introspection is currently broken (with Python at least)...

## 1. Short code example

Let's try this piece of code to obtain a `GParamSpec` struct:

```
# Various imports
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
Gst.init(None)

# Create a Gstreamer element
element = Gst.ElementFactory.make("lamemp3enc")
bitrate_property = element.find_property("bitrate")
```

Now if I do,

```
>>> type(bitrate_property)
gobject.GParamSpec
```

All seems fine as the `GParamSpec` structure is what [various useful functions](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-GParamSpec.html) feed on.

## 2. Problem

However, if I try to actually use these structures in Python, I get an exception with absolutely no hint in order to sort things out:

```
>>> GObject.ParamSpec.get_name(bitrate_property)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-63f0daaa3a81> in <module>()
----> 1 GObject.ParamSpec.get_name(bitrate_property)

TypeError: argument self: Expected GObject.ParamSpec, but got gobject.GParamSpec
```

## 3. Obvious problem, no solution?

The problem is **obvious**: it is expecting a `ParamSpec` object but it gets
a `GParamSpec` object instead. However,

- The doc seems to imply that `GParamSpec` is the correct object (at least in C);
- `find_property` returns a `GParamSpec`, just like it does in C;
- there are no equivalent functions in `GObject.GParamSpec` yet such functions *do* exist (at least in C);
- even if a cast is needed, **there is no obvious way** to cast a `gobject.GParamSpec` to a `GObject.ParamSpec` as requested.

Is that a bug? Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness, my ultimate purpose is to retrieve valid values from `GParamSpec` struct. *Not* their current/default ones. I also want to check whether the value I gave to the `set_property` method has been accepted. I want the `GParamSpec` type, its valid range (if applicable) or the list of possible values (in enums). Most of that is already implemented in the functions in `GObject.ParamSpec`.

Comment: I know nothing about Python introspection, but I think the data you eventually want is on a subtype of GParamSpec, like GParamSpecInt.  Can you downcast to that and pull it off the struct members?  https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#GParamSpecInt

Comment: Apparently, the `GObject.ParamSpec` vs `gobject.GParamSpec` is pygobject3 limitation: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what’s going on with `GObject.ParamSpec` vs `gobject.GParamSpec`, but you can access members of the param spec as properties:

```
>>> bitrate_property = element.find_property('bitrate')
>>> print(bitrate_property)
<GParamInt 'bitrate'>
>>> type(bitrate_property)
<type 'gobject.GParamSpec'>
>>> bitrate_property.name
'bitrate'
>>> bitrate_property.minimum
8
>>> bitrate_property.maximum
320
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `gparamstring` appears to be a property which is passed to a signal hander. The value of the property can be extracted by `GObject.get_property` as shown below

```
def handler(obj, gparamstring):
    property_value = obj.get_property(gparamstring.name)
```